# Load TabPanel Item content dynamically ext.js 5.1.3

Tags: typescript, extjs

I am working on extJs 5.1.3 version. I want to load items of a tabpanel from an Array. But the problem is it is loading for the indefinite time in the browser and not showing my tabpanel. Here is my code below,

```
this.myPanel = new Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        height: 500,
        activeTab: 0,
        items: [
            myEntities.forEach(function (item) {
                this.midPanel.add({
                    title: item.box.id,
                    html: "<iframe width ='100%' height='100%' src='/myPage.aspx?id='+ item.box.id +''><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>"
                })
            })
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

The code is working for static items. For example,

```
this.myPanel = new Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        height: 500,
        activeTab: 0,
        items: [
            title: "X",
                    html: "<iframe width ='100%' height='100%' src='/myPage.aspx?id=123'><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>"
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

I am just wondering where am I doing the mistake for dynamic item loading in the TabPanel. Thanks in advance if someone can show me the problem or a demo.

Comment: can you prepare sencha fiddle to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was bit tricky for me as a beginner. I solved it by loading the items in another Panel and refer it to the midPanel items attribute. Here is my final solution,

```
        var tabs = [];
    myEntities.forEach(function (item) {
        tabs.push(Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            title: "Box Id: " + item.box.id,
            html: '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="../myPage.aspx?id=' + item.box.id +'"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>'
        }))
    });

    this.midPanel = new Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        height: 500,
        activeTab: 0,
        items: tabs,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```